# Issue with HV boost converter using TL5001

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, boost

I have a boost converter circuit that (should) convert from 12V input to 500V output with a TL5001 PWM controller.
The problem I'm having is that the TL5001 PWM controller doesn't seem to be doing anything. When I plug in the circuit the output spikes to around 450V and then falls down as the output capacitor settles.

Here is the circuit diagram I'm using, which is basically a power supply portion of the MIT's DIY Geiger Counter lab guide found on [6th page](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-s902-do-it-yourself-diy-geiger-counters-january-iap-2015/labs/MIT22_S902IAP15_gc_instruct.pdf) with the exception of different HV sense resistor values and other closest replacement parts that are mostly SMD.
[image]

I've measured the OUT pin of the TL5001 and it looks like that the OUT pin is only activated first 75ms of powering the circuit, after that due to OUT pin closing the output voltage spikes:

[image]
[image]

I've also checked the FB pin voltage and seems about right, reaching 852mV when the output is at 440V (TL5001 should be trying to reach 1V).

Any ideas on what could be wrong or what else to look for?

Comment: What does "OUT pin closing the output" mean? Is that closing like a switch and allowing current to flow, or closing like a door and preventing current from flowing?

Comment: Consider lowering the resistance values of your feedback just to test if that is the issue. My first guess is that the high feedback resistors voltage on the feedback pin to rise very slowly. This can activate the scp.

Comment: 10k and the input capacitance of Q3 is going to slow the turn on time to around 5us. What is the switching frequency?

Comment: Does the circuit work if you applied a 1 Mohm load resistor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work. There seemed to be 2 issues with the circuit.

First the R11 value of RT that dictates the switching frequency was too large, based on the datasheet it says that the acceptable resistor values are between 15kΩ and 250kΩ for 500kHz and 20kHz respectively. I have no clue of why the 6.8MΩ was chosen. As a replacement I've put 500kΩ resistor.

Second issue was indeed the resistance value of the feedback loop being too high, which due to low response triggered SCP (as suggested in the question comments). Lowering the resistance (by shorting one of the 2.74MΩ) and with the above modification made TL5001 active and output the expected voltage (based on the new feedback configuration ofcourse).

Comment: Thanks for reporting back!

Comment: I know it has been a while, but why did you choose to replace the 6.8MΩ resistor with a 500kΩ resistor? 500kΩ is still not in the 15-250kΩ range.